# Python script runs in ArcCatalog and ArcToolbox, but not in PyScripter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, pyscripter

I have a script that imports a custom toolbox, copies data from an sde to a file/personal gdb, removes custom feature class extensions, etc. The script runs fine in Catalog, but I receive the following error in PyScripter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Clients\Custom.py", line 45, in <module>
    arcpy.UpdateMDB(gisIn, wsOut)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UpdateMDB'
```

`UpdateMDB` is a toolbox tool and the portion of the problem script that copies data to a file or personal gdb. The tool runs great in Toolbox. On a co-worker's machine, `arcpy.UpdateMDB` runs correctly in the same script, but throws an error on mine. I've also seen references for `arcpy.Update_tools` and `arcpy.UpdateMDB_Company_Tools` in help documents, but these also throw an error.

In the problematic script, I'm importing my custom toolbox like this:

```
tbx = r'C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Company Tools.tbx'
```

I'm running ArcGIS 10.2.2 on a 32-bit computer. We do a lot of testing in PyScripter, so I'm trying to figure this one out. It seems like it could be an easy fix - any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a Python Path issue. Both ArcMap and Catalog use python in some like "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3" pyScripter may be set to use a different interpreter.

Comment: At the top of the script, I sometimes add the script folder to PythonPath.  thisdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(thisdir)

Comment: Have you  tried passing tbx to the arcpy.ImportToolbox function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. The problem seemed to be that the custom toolbox was located in two locations and was causing a conflict. The toolbox was located in the default location:
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Company Tools.tbx
and also here:
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Company Tools.tbx

Before deleting the duplicate, I tried renaming the tbx and then changing the alias, but this did not work.

Once the tbx under Desktop10.2 was deleted, the scripts ran correctly. Having duplicate toolboxes was not a problem when running the tools from ArcCatalog and ArcMap python windows, only when testing in PyScripter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `tbx = arcpy.ImportToolbox (path_to_tbx)`